# Calling javascript function when html is executed

Tags: javascript, html

I have one task, when I open the html page, that html contains javascript under script tag, and under which I have implemented one function called `auther()`. How can I call this function while opening the html page, I don't want to implement it by using `onClick` or `onLoad`, etc. methods from html/javascript.

Means whenever my html gets executed my javascript function should get called itself. Following is my html:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Demo</title>
   </head>
<body>
  <div id="authOps" >
      <button onclick="auther();">GET author</button>
      //By clicking on this button it is working but I want to execute 
      //this function when this html get executed
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function auther(){
      //some code
   }
</script>
</html>
```

In the above scenario whenever my html page is opened, the javascript function should get executed without any click handling.

**Note :** I have mentioned html code just for reference purpose, My main purpose just to execute javascript function, how can I achieve this??

Comment: `the javascript function should get executed without any click handling`, why would a handler run without the event being fired? and also servlet just spits out html, it doesn't do any html processing itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this as far as i know,

**1:**

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Demo</title>
   </head>
<body>
  <div id="authOps" >
      <button onclick="auther();">GET author</button>
      //By clicking on this button it is working but I want to execute 
      //this function when this html get executed
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function auther(){
 console.log("Hi");
   };
auther();
</script>
</html>
```

**2:**

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Demo</title>
   </head>
<body>
  <div id="authOps" >
      <button >GET author</button>
      //By clicking on this button it is working but I want to execute 
      //this function when this html get executed
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var thisIsAFunction = function (){
 console.log("Hi");
   }();
</script>
</html>
```

You can give a try with both options.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the method in a script block, instead of from the button click

```
<script>auther(); </script>
```

Comment: I also tried this, but on runtime browser is throwing exception saying undefined method

Comment: exact error is,"Uncaught ReferenceError: auther is not defined "

Comment: That's because you called it before it was declared. That's why it's working in @Gowtham Shivas first example